# Trying to combine flags within enum value

Tags: c++, enums

Trying to construct a simple enum to contain a set of ios:: flags for easier reference, parameter passing, etc.  I want to be able to make a call:

```
resultCode = DoSomething(param, TRUNCATE);

ResultCode DoSomething(int param, FileOperation_t operation) {...}
```

I have defined my enum thusly:

```
typedef enum {
    TRUNCATE = std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc,
    APPEND   = std::ios::out | std::ios::app
} FileOperation_t;
```

Compiling this results in:

```
error: calls to overloaded operators cannot appear in a constant-expression
     TRUNCATE = std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc,
                                          ^
```

I do not understand what this error means.  What am I doing wrong here and how do I accomplish what I am trying to do?

**gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)**

Comment: What compiler/version are you using?

Comment: @NathanOliver  Reproduced on gcc up to version 5.5, fine starting 6.1

Comment: The standard says the type of the value is implementation defined, are you sure it's integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compiler seems to use `-std=c++98` by default. Use `-std=c++11` flag instead and the code will compile.

In C++98 function calls (including overloaded opeator calls) weren't allowed in compile-time constant expressions (since there were no `constexpr` semantics).

---

Though, it's not *required* to compile according to the standard, even with the flag:

[This page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BitmaskType) says `std::ios::openmode` is a `typedef` for an implementation-define type, satisfying [BitmaskType](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BitmaskType) concept.

While BitmaskType has to have operator overloads for `&`, `|` and so on, there is no guarantee that these operators are constexpr, nor that the type itself is convertible to an integral type.

For maximum compatibility, use plain `const` variables instead:

```
const std::ios::openmode TRUNCATE = std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc;
const std::ios::openmode APPEND   = std::ios::out | std::ios::app;
```

(This solution will also work with C++98, if you can't use newer standards.)

Comment: If an overloaded operator can't appear in a constant-expression, then how does this answer solve that? Isn't TRUNCATE a constant? And isn't TRUNCATE = std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc a constant-expression?

Comment: @Displayname Here 'constant expression' probably means 'compile-time constant expression'. You can initialize `const` variables with non-const expressions. But it turns out the problem was caused not by a typedef being implemented poorly, but rather by a missing `-std=c++11` flag.

Comment: I cannot use C++11.. we are stuck with C++98 for the present.  Further, I could not use the `auto` keyword. I had to `#include <ios>` and then `const std::ios_base::openmode TRUNCATE = std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc;`.

Comment: I am still unclear on the meaning of the error though.. what operator have I overloaded (I have not, to my knowledge) and what is the error telling me here?

Comment: @Jon 1) The standard library overloads `|` for `std::ios_base::openmode`. 2) Enumerator values have to be compile-time constants. But function calls can't be used in compile-time constant expressions (except C++11 `constexpr` function calls).